# ListView check for max chat limit tresspassing

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Is there anyway I can auto check a character limit in a ListView, by changing the background color to orange or some other color for any item violating a limit?

This goes in an event of imported text; after the importing, it loops through all the items and checks if the items violate the limit. If they do, they should get Coral background color, but it's not working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numpntr; i++)
{
    int charlim = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);

    if (charlim > bytecnt)
    {
        listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Coral;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working possibly because the `SubItems[1]` doesn't have such a long text as you expect. You should debug (step-by-step or add watch) to see the values of `charlim`. That would make everything clear.

Comment: to Grant: numpntr: number of strings, bytecnt: character limit, my datasource is a list of strings, @KingKing: actually it does, tested it more than a few times, still no result.

Comment: it's a text file, that has numpntr number of lines, each line contains 2 strings separated by a char "^", each string is for a column, so when importing it imports each string to it's own column, so, i only want to check teh second column.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
int charlim = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
```

To:

```
int charlim = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(listView1.Items[i].Text);
```

It's work for me.

Comment: each item contains minimum of two columns (other are 3 and 4), so i only want to check the subitem[1], and by removing it, it'll only check subitem[0]